# I want to update my quantity at the same time based on quantity update my available quantity and sell quantity

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-redux, redux-toolkit

suppose i have `quantity`, `available_qty`, and `sell_quantity` ,I want if my `quantity` increase my `sell_quantity` will increase and `available_qty` decrease ,if my `quantity` will decrease my `sell_quantity` will decrease and `available_qty` will increase..

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import BackButton from '../../components/UI/BackButton'
import Input from '../../components/UI/Input'
import Button from '../../components/UI/Button'

import {
  useUpdateOrderMutation,
  useGetOrderByIdQuery,
  useGetAllProductQuery,
  useGetAllOrderQuery,
} from '../../Redux/Services/services'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const UpdateOrder = () => {
  const [noData, setNoData] = useState(false)

  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitSuccessful },
  } = useForm({
    // resolver: yupResolver(createProductSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      //   Category_name: '',
      //   subCat_name: '',
      selling_price: '',
      quantity: '',
      available_qty: '',
      sell_quantity: '',
      //   unit: '',
      total_cost: '',
    },
  })
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (formState.isSubmitSuccessful) {
      reset({ quantity: '' })
    }
  }, [formState, reset])
  const params = useParams()
  const order_id = params.id

  const [updateOrder, responseInfoOrderUpdate] = useUpdateOrderMutation()

  const responseInfoOrderById = useGetOrderByIdQuery(order_id)

  const responseInfoProduct = useGetAllProductQuery()
  const responseInfoAllOrder = useGetAllOrderQuery()
  const orderDetails = responseInfoAllOrder.data
  if (responseInfoOrderUpdate.isLoading) return <div>Loading....</div>
  if (responseInfoOrderUpdate.isError)
    return <h1>An error occured {responseInfoOrderUpdate.error.error}</h1>

  if (responseInfoOrderById.isLoading) return <div>Loading....</div>
  if (responseInfoOrderById.isError)
    return <h1>An error occured {responseInfoOrderById.error.error}</h1>

  if (responseInfoProduct.isLoading) return <div>Loading....</div>
  if (responseInfoProduct.isError)
    return <h1>An error occured {responseInfoProduct.error.error}</h1>
  // const totalProductQty = responseInfoOrderById.data
  //   ?.filter((sellQuantity) => sellQuantity.subCat_id === subCat_id)
  //   .map((additionSell, i) => additionSell.quantity)
  //   .reduce((qty, purchase) => qty + purchase, 0)
  var qty_data = responseInfoOrderById.data?.quantity
  var sellingPrice_data = responseInfoOrderById.data?.selling_price
  var available_qty = responseInfoOrderById.data?.available_qty
  var sell_quantity = responseInfoOrderById.data?.sell_quantity

  const totalProductQty =
    parseInt(responseInfoOrderById.data?.available_qty) +
    parseInt(responseInfoOrderById.data?.sell_quantity)
  console.log('totalProductQty', totalProductQty)
  console.log('sell_quantity', sell_quantity)

  const sell_qty =
    parseInt(totalProductQty) -
    parseInt(responseInfoOrderById.data?.available_qty)
  // const available_qty =
  //   parseInt(totalProductQty) -
  //   parseInt(responseInfoOrderById.data?.sell_quantity)
  // console.log('sell_qty', sell_qty)
  // console.log('available_qty', available_qty)

  // const total_sell = parseInt(sellQty) + parseInt(quantity)
  const AvailableProduct = parseInt(totalProductQty) - parseInt(qty_data)

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const orderUpdateData = {
      id: order_id,
      quantity: data.quantity,
      available_qty: available_qty,
      selling_price: data.selling_price,
      total_cost: data.total_cost,
      sell_quantity: sell_quantity,
    }
    updateOrder(orderUpdateData)

    console.log(orderUpdateData, 'orderUpdateData')
  }

  var total_cost = parseInt(sellingPrice_data) * parseInt(qty_data)
  console.log('supplier_name', sellingPrice_data, qty_data, total_cost)
  setValue('quantity', qty_data)
  setValue('selling_price', sellingPrice_data)
  setValue('total_cost', total_cost)
  setValue('available_qty', available_qty)
  setValue('sell_quantity', sell_quantity)
  return (
    <div className="page__wrapper">
      <BackButton />

      <div className="place__order__wrapper">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="inputs__cover">
            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
              }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  label="Selling price"
                  type="number"
                  id="selling_price"
                  readOnly={true}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
              name="selling_price"
            />
            {errors.selling_price && (
              <span className="field_error">This is required.</span>
            )}

            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
              }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  label="Available qty"
                  type="number"
                  id="available_qty"
                  readOnly={true}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
              name="available_qty"
            />
            {errors.available_qty && (
              <span className="field_error">This is required.</span>
            )}

            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
              }}
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  label="sell Total qty"
                  type="number"
                  id="sell_quantity"
                  readOnly={true}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  value={value}
                />
              )}
              name="sell_quantity"
            />
            {errors.sell_quantity && (
              <span className="field_error">This is required.</span>
            )}

            <div className="quantity__input">
              <Controller
                control={control}
                rules={{
                  required: true,
                }}
                render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                  <Input
                    label="Quantity"
                    type="number"
                    id="quantity"
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onBlur={onBlur}
                    value={value}
                  />
                )}
                name="quantity"
              />
            </div>

            <Controller
              control={control}
              rules={
                {
                  // required: true,
                }
              }
              render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
                <Input
                  label="Total cost"
                  type="number"
                  id="total_cost"
                  onChange={onChange}
                  onBlur={onBlur}
                  value={noData ? total_cost.toString() : value}
                  readOnly={true}
                />
              )}
              name="total_cost"
            />
            {errors.total_cost && (
              <span className="field_error">This is required.</span>
            )}
          </div>

          <div className="button__wrapper">
            <Button className="add__product__button" type="submit">
              Add quantity
            </Button>
          </div>
          <div className="button__wrapper">
            <Button className="add__product__button" type="submit">
              update quantity
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default UpdateOrder
```

model is

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //convert id to normal form
    customer_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    category_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    subCat_id: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    selling_price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    sell_quantity: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    available_qty: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    unit: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      enum: {
        values: ["kg", "litre", "pcs", "bag"],
        message: "unit must be kg/litre/pcs/bag",
      },
    },
    total_cost: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("order", OrderSchema);
```

query is

```js
const router = require("express").Router();
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const Order = require("../models/Order");
//create order
router.post("/order-save", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const customer_id = req.body.customer_id;
    const category_id = req.body.category_id;
    const subCat_id = req.body.subCat_id;
    const selling_price = req.body.selling_price;
    const quantity = req.body.quantity;
    const sell_quantity = req.body.sell_quantity;
    const available_qty = req.body.available_qty;
    const unit = req.body.unit;
    const total_cost = req.body.total_cost;
    const oder_data = new Order({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      customer_id: customer_id,
      category_id: category_id,
      subCat_id: subCat_id,
      selling_price: selling_price,
      quantity: quantity,
      sell_quantity: sell_quantity,
      available_qty: available_qty,
      unit: unit,
      total_cost: total_cost,
    });
    const orderData = await oder_data.save();
    message = "Order Create Successfully..";
    return res.status(200).json(orderData);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(200).json(err);
  }
});
//get all order
router.get("/get-order", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const order = await Order.find();
    return res.status(200).json(order);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(200).json(err);
  }
});
//get order by id
router.get("/get-order/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orderById = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
    return res.status(200).json(orderById);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
//get filter customer by id
router.get("/filter-order/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const order = await Order.find({ $and: [{ customer_id: req.params.id }] });
    return res.status(200).json(order);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//Update Order
router.patch("/update-order/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      new: true,
    });
    message = "Order has been updated...";
    return res.status(200).json({ message });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(200).json(err);
  }
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?  Something isn't working?  How is something not working?  If you show a before/after document, perhaps it might make your question clearer.

Comment: my output is quantity is updated but the available quantity and sell quantity is not updated

Comment: `await Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, ...`  What is `req.body` here? _"... available quantity and sell quantity is not updated"_  Not updated in the database?

Comment: req.body is whatever data I am sending that will update here

Comment: i want to perform operation on frontend

Comment: So this question is NOT about MongoDB?